# Trying to obtain this output (operations on palindromes in Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, stack, palindrome

I am trying to get my codes to print this output.

it will take in string. take in word (what i'm supposed to do)
i am supposed to compare 1st word and the last word in the string
then if it is a palindrome it will return true. if not it will return false
here is my code

```
def palindrome_word(a_str):
outputlist = []
bad_character = [' ', '?', ',']
for element in a_str:
    for words in bad_character:
        element = element.replace(words, '')
        element = element.lower()
        outputlist.append(element == element[::-1])
        return outputlist
my_string=["King, are you you are king?"]
print(palindrome_word(my_string))
```

I'm trying to have this as my output but got errors 
output :

[True, False]

My output:
[False, False]

Comment: `king...king` is not a palindrome. `king...gnik` is a palindrome.

Comment: why is my_string and a_str a list?  Thats confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you want to reverse the order of words, not characters, so you should `split` on whitespace rather than remove it:

```
words = element.split()
words == words[::-1]
```

where `bad_character = ['?', ',']` (basically any punctuation, so you could also use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation).

Comment: @NurAishah Indeed you first need to split to get the words, then do the comparison. Please try again.